# Character Encoding Issue with XML and PHP file_get_contents

Tags: character-encoding, xml-parsing

I've been having a problem with character encoding from an XML API and can't seem to fix the problem. I was wondering if someone would know how to go about this. I have tried the following pieces of code and they both produce some weird character encoding issues.

THE CODE #1

```
$xml_url = "http://myurl.com/123.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_url);
```

THE CODE #2

```
$xml_url = "http://myurl.com/123.xml";
$contents = file_get_contents($xml_url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($contents);
```

The way that some characters such as apostrophes are coming out are like this

```
strengthening resumÃ©s
```

There are hundreds of errors with this. The top of my code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
```

I've tried removing it as well as putting it as HTML 5 and I can't seem to get anything. I've tried other latin character encoding etc and it just gets worse and worse. Does anyone have any thoughts on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

When UTF-8 encoded text `é` is viewed as ISO-8859-1 encoded text, it appears as `Ã©`.

If I recall correctly, SimpleXML works only with UTF-8 encoded data. So you need to encode all files that you read in and also text strings that you add to your document (before using SimpleXML methods on them), if your data is not UTF-8. You can use `iconv()` or `utf8_encode()` for conversion.

Also check the encoding of your code file if your code has non-ASCII literals.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I apologize for my lack of knowledge on char encoding, but where would I use the utf8_encode? Would it be on the actual XML values inside (ie. $xml->thisValue) or on the actual URL itself?

Comment: Alright. I'm half way there it seems. I was able to get the Ã© to change to the é using utf8_decode(), however, there are other encoding issues with apostrophes come out like this when stored in mysql : â€™

Comment: @SamOh That is the same problem: a curly apostrophe encoded with UTF-8 looks like `â€™` when viewed as ISO-8859-1 text. Make sure you use proper encoding settings when connecting to your database. Use decode or encode functions on all text received/stored to database if neccessary. Keeping everything (input, output, database, file storage) as Unicode is a good way to avoid charset conversions and thus problems related to it.

Comment: I tried to do the utf8_encode and decode on the INSERT INTO statement itself and it didn't work. Also tried on the actual text and it's still producing the error and it's not a matter of cache. I'm not quite sure why this is still happening. I guess I'll just have to live with it. I appreciate your help jasso.